# Python: Syntax Error (+=)

Tags: python, syntax-error

why am i getting a syntax error using += in this simple function ?

```
def downloadImages(urllist):
  counter = 0 
  for url in urllist:
    downloadSingleImage(url, (filename_prefix + str(counter))
    counter += 1
```

Comment: When in doubt, look at the previous line with parens..

Comment: you do not need the paren before `filename_prefix`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parens are not balanced on the line `downloadSingleImage(url, (filename_prefix + str(counter))`.

Comment: Thanks, it Worked, will accept as soon as m allowed. cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one parentese on the end.

```
def downloadImages(urllist):
  counter = 0 
  for url in urllist:
    downloadSingleImage(url, (filename_prefix + str(counter)))
    counter += 1
```